# Quartz.NET JobDataMap Last_Modified_Time serialization exception

Tags: quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET to fire off a very basic (proof of concept) job that checks for new records and sends e-mails if any exist. I want other programmers to be able to modify their jobs via the jobs file.

However, Quartz.NET never checks the file for changes. From observation, it looks like every time it checks, it tries to store the `LAST_MODIFIED_TIME` in its database (ADO.NET, MSSQL), and fails to serialize the date. I've tried using both quartz.config and the `<quartz>` configuration section within the application's standard config file, but both ultimately produce the same error.

I've researched this topic and found an [existing issue logged in Quartz.NET's GitHub site](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/44), which was posted in 2012. At this point, it looks like the developer is unable to fix this issue. Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is not easy to implement cleanly. You could just have useproperties configuration as false and this would work.

Comment: I actually tried that, and I got serialization errors when Quartz tried to save to SQL.

Comment: Sigh. Nevermind -- the exception it threw was in trying to read data from the database and convert from a `NameValueCollection` to an `IDictionary`.

Comment: Case of having mixed data on db will be supported in next patch release though.